# Using HTML Object Tag viewing last page of PDF or scroll to last page of PDF

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, object-tag

I am displaying PDF in the browser through Object Tag but I have to scroll down to the last page after loading, is it possible or any other solution?

Comment: can you please provide some of your code, and describe what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Actually, I got the solution you can pass parameters with PDF path in data field e.g xyz.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0
so if I pass "page=100" and my PDF has 12 pages it will show 12th (last) page

Comment: that is great, do you mind if i add it as an answer so if anyone else has the same question they can easily use your solution

Comment: sure, it will be great

Answer (score 2):

The following parameters are commonly used to embed PDF file in HTML or open in the browser.

`page=pagenum` – Specifies a number (integer) of the page in the document. The document’s first page has a pagenum value of 1, for example if you pass `"page=100"` and your PDF has 12 pages it will show 12th (last) page.

`zoom=scale` – Sets the zoom and scroll factors, using float or integer values. For example, a scale value of 100 indicates a zoom value of 100%.

`view=Fit` – Set the view of the displayed page.

`scrollbar=1|0` – Turns scrollbars on or off.

`toolbar=1|0` – Turns the toolbar on or off.

`statusbar=1|0` – Turns the status bar on or off.

`navpanes=1|0` – Turns the navigation panes and tabs on or off.